# Google Apps Script, script completed but did not return anything

Tags: google-apps-script

I've shared an App i'm working on with "Anyone who has the link", yet i can't access the app as a different user.

Here's the App link: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxjdyMyvIF8aYDBPurTi4VgVBP8PiiS76vh3mJXKCtFmljdmChK/exec
Here's a sample App link i shared with similar settings that worked: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTM_gkT62IqpKjG52ZMh6LWo-gBKZyfcpmrrqNavdiuC71KsNv/exec

**App Deployment Settings:**

```
*Execute the app as: my_email@gmail.com

Who has access to the app: Anyone

The app uses ScriptDB.*
```

My App will be useless if it can't be eventually accessed publicly. Your suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `doGet` function in your code returns nothing and it should return a new app instance or HTML content, like in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#CreatingHTML). You have to change the `doGet` function in the following way.

```
function doGet(e){
  //...
  return html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't the doGet though.
I simply had to Create a new Version of My Project since updating the previous version did not update its sharing settings.

Comment: It would have been great that Google did include that into their documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization). Thanks @ChelaTheGreat!

Comment: Hey Google, wake up! Are you not seeing this issue has been confusing everyone for years? Just add a note that the app must be republished, damn it!