# Is it possible to run a google script with the web app URL on the New Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

I was playing around with a macro-nutrient calculator that I wanted to make. I was trying to create a cleanup function for the spreadsheet which would be accessed by clicking a link to a script from the site. Here is what I have so far:

```
function doGet(){
  function ClearMacros(){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEETID');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Fat Entries');
    sheet.getRange('A2:B1001').clearContent();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Protein Entries');
    sheet.getRange('A2:B1001').clearContent();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Carb Entries');
    sheet.getRange('A2:B1001').clearContent();
  }
}
```

Results:
Error: The script completed but did not return anything.

When I run it from the script IDE it works, so I am not sure why it isn't working when I click the link to the web app.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), a script can be published as a web app if it meets these requirements:

- It contains a `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` function.
- The function returns an [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) `HtmlOutput` object or a Content service `TextOutput` object.

As referred in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984250/5832311), try to create a new version of `My Project` because maybe updating the previous version did not update its sharing settings.